# Не может найти файл для чтения из памяти телефона

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

Нужно выбрать файл затем его добавить в таблицу БД и вывести в `ImageView`. В `ImageView` выводит, но вот в таблицу БД не добавляет и за ошибки

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A249394 (No such file or directory)
```

не может найти файл. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем ошибка?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    ImageView imageView;
    public static DBConnection dbConnection = null;
    public FileInputStream fis = null;
    public File file = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    }

    public void performFileSearch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    public void cloclk(View view) {
        performFileSearch();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent resultData) {

        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                System.out.println("URL" +uri);
                file = new File(String.valueOf(uri));
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file); //вот здесь ошибка
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dbConnection = new DBConnection(ParamDB.host,ParamDB.name,ParamDB.password,ParamDB.nameDB);
                        dbConnection.iniProperties();
                        dbConnection.init();
                        dbConnection.updateQuery("UPDATE student SET logo=? WHERE email= 'user1'",fis,file);

                    }
                }).start();


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    try {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(uri));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Лог ошибки:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A249394 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at com.example.filedialog.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7109)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1599)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Comment: Похоже что вы не правильно достаете объекты из `URI`, посмотрите эту [ссылку](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

Comment: Я как раз так и делаю

Comment: я ничего не знаю про андроид, а двоеточие в пути это норма? я про `image%3A249394` где `%3A` это `:` ?

Comment: uri = resultData.getData();